# angular ui-layout not working with angular v1.3.15

Tags: angularjs, layout, angular-ui

Would like to know if angular-ui/ui-layout will work angular v1.3.15. It seems to be not working. I just want to create a simple 2 column layout with size of 20% & 80%

this is the code

```
<div ui-layout="{ flow : 'column', sizes: [ '300px' ] }" style="height:100vh;">
      <div ui-layout-container size="10%" minsize="10%"></div>
      <div ui-layout-container size="90%"></div>
</div>
```

Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'flow' of undefined
    at link (http://localhost:5021/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-layout.js?v=1.0:50:54)

Comment: Please post your code. Or better a plnkr that we can take a look at. Without that it is pretty hard to suggest anything in your case.

Comment: updated with code, i don't have plunker at work.